# Having trouble listen vert.x config change

Tags: java, vert.x

I changed my config-test.json,but application did not print "new config:...",the before scanhander has print .

```
        JsonObject jsonConfig = new JsonObject();
        jsonConfig.put("path", "test.json");
        ConfigStoreOptions config = new ConfigStoreOptions();
        config.setType("file").setOptional(true).setConfig(jsonConfig);
        
        ConfigRetrieverOptions options =
                new ConfigRetrieverOptions().addStore(config).setScanPeriod(5000);
        ConfigRetriever configRetriever = ConfigRetriever.create(vertx, options);
        configRetriever.setBeforeScanHandler(h -> {
            System.out.println("config:" + configRetriever.getCachedConfig());
        });
        configRetriever.listen(change -> {
            JsonObject newConfiguration = change.getNewConfiguration();
            System.out.println("new config:" + newConfiguration);
            JsonObject old = change.getPreviousConfiguration();
            System.out.println("old config:" + old);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc of `setBeforeScanHandler` says:

> Registers a handler called before every scan. This method is mostly used for logging purpose.

Which means that in your case the program will check for changes in the JSON file every five seconds as specified in `.setScanPeriod(5000)`. If the program finds the change during one of those checks, first the `configRetriever.setBeforeScanHandler` method will trigger, followed by `configRetriever.listen`.

The order of messages when there is a change will be:

```
config : {...} 
new config:{...} 
old config:{...}
```

The program does not register the config change immediately, but only on the regularly scheduled interval checks, as is stated in the `setScanPeriod` JavaDoc:

> Configures the scan period, in ms. This is the time amount between two
> checks of the configuration updates.

Comment: I have solve it .my path is error.