# Vert.x ConfigRetriever.listen does not get triggered when the config file changes

Tags: vert.x

I have a simple vertical that I am using to test the ConfigRetriever.listen for changes.

Using Vert.x version 4.3.4

```java
import io.vertx.config.ConfigRetriever;
import io.vertx.config.ConfigRetrieverOptions;
import io.vertx.config.ConfigStoreOptions;
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;

public class MyVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    @Override
    public void start() {
        ConfigStoreOptions fileStore = new ConfigStoreOptions().setType("file")
                                                               .setFormat("yaml")
                                                               .setConfig(new JsonObject().put("path", "config.yaml"));

        ConfigRetrieverOptions options = new ConfigRetrieverOptions().setScanPeriod(1000)
                                                                     .addStore(fileStore);

        ConfigRetriever retriever = ConfigRetriever.create(vertx, options);





        retriever.listen(change -> {
            JsonObject previous = change.getPreviousConfiguration();
            System.out.println(previous);
            JsonObject changedConf = change.getNewConfiguration();
            System.out.println(changedConf);

        });
    }
}
```

[Edit] The config file is under `src/main/resource`
When I run this, I get an output of the before as empty and after as config in my yaml file.

```
{}
{"bridgeservice":{"eb_address":"xyz","path":"/api/v1/aaa/","port":80}}
```

The problem is when I change the value in the yaml config file nothing happens. I expect the changes to get printed. When I am running this in the debugger I see

```
Thread [vert.x-internal-blocking-0] (Running)   
..
..
..
Thread [vert.x-internal-blocking-19] (Running)
```

When I put the following just before the `retriever.listen()` , I get the `succeeded...` line printed and nothing from the listen method even after changing the config file values.

```java
        retriever.getConfig(ar -> {
            if (ar.succeeded()) {
                System.out.println("succeeded :" + ar.result());
            }
            else {
                ar.cause()
                  .printStackTrace();
            }

        });
```

[May be related to SO having-trouble-listen-vert-x-config-change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72377502/having-trouble-listen-vert-x-config-change)

[Edit] The config file is under `src/main/resource`

Answer (score 0):

When I moved my config file from resources to a folder cfg at the same level as src the Verticle behaved as it should and picked up config changes. I don't know why, maybe it's an eclipse environment thing.